# Xpath interactable only when full path is used, not when 'contains' is used

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is my first question asked here. Most of the time I have been able to figure things out with other peoples question but this goes a bit over my head.

I seem to be able to click an element by using the XPath. However, the XPath changes from time to time so I tried finding a more generic expression for it. This is where I have become stuck.

I have the following piece of HTML code from a website. I am trying to click a button to get the underlying information to show. *Please mind* that I have extracted the XPath in the code below by right clicking on this piece of code in my browser and clicking "Copy full XPath"

```
<button data-testid="closed-odp-show-all-info" class="c-button-template u-cursor-pointer c-button__container c-button--secondary u-color-brand u-typography-h7 u-m-t-xl">
  <span class="c-button__overlay"></span>
  <span class="c-button__content">
    <span class="c-button__label">Show all info</span>
  </span>
</button>
```

The piece of code which I am working on currently looks like this (if indentation seems not correct, something went wrong with copy-pasting, in code it is correct):

```
else:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/footer/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    driver.close()
    keys = soup.find_all(class_="be-lot-specification__name u-typography-label-s u-typography-uppercase u-color-dark-gray")
    values = soup.find_all(class_='be-lot-specification__value u-typography-body')
    keys = [key.text for key in keys]
    keys.append("Prijs")
    values = [value.text for value in values]
    values.append(higest_price)
    try:
        values[1] = values[1].strip("(More Lots)")
    except Exception:
        pass

    df1 = dict(zip(keys, values))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, index=[count])
    self.dataset = pd.concat([df1, self.dataset])
```

This piece of code is working, however, I found out that some of the "div[x" changes sometime so I tried writing a more generic locator that then would extract the XPath. Just like I practically did manually before. However, when I try to write the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@data-testid,closed-odp-show-all-info)]').click()
```

I get the following error code:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I have also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class,c-button-template u-cursor-pointer c-button__container c-button--secondary u-color-brand u-typography-h7 u-m-t-xl)]').click()
```

but then I get the error code:

```
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the XPath expression //button[contains(@class,c-button-template u-cursor-pointer c-button__container c-button--secondary u-color-brand u-typography-h7 u-m-t-xl)] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[contains(@class,c-button-template u-cursor-pointer c-button__container c-button--secondary u-color-brand u-typography-h7 u-m-t-xl)]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

I just discovered that the `data-testid` value is not unique, however, the class value is unique.

Lastly, I tried using the following:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='class,c-button-template u-cursor-pointer c-button__container c-button--secondary u-color-brand u-typography-h7 u-m-t-xl)]")))
element.click()
```

but then I got: "TimeoutException: Message: "

My question is, how am I going to be able to extract the information I need assuming my step to click the button to reveal the information and locate that button by using the method above is correct with an changing XPath?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues I see:

1. You aren't putting quotes around the various XPath values

   ```
   '//button[contains(@data-testid,closed-odp-show-all-info)]'
   ```

   should be

   ```
   '//button[contains(@data-testid,"closed-odp-show-all-info")]'
                                   ^                        ^
   ```
2. Also, you are using `contains` when you don't need to.

   ```
   '//button[@data-testid="closed-odp-show-all-info"]'
   ```

   `contains` is for substring searches. If you are matching the full string, omit `contains`.
3. Without seeing the page, I can't answer why you are getting the message, "element not interactable". That means that the element you are clicking is not something that accepts a click. That would be odd for a BUTTON but maybe it's a timing issue and if you waited for clickable, it would work?
4. The `invalid selector` error message is because of #1.
5. The timeout exception on the last locator is because you've mixed in part of the `contains` syntax with the actual XPath.

   ```
   "//button[@class='class,c-button-template u-cursor-pointer c-button__container c-button--secondary u-color-brand u-typography-h7 u-m-t-xl)]"
                     ^^^^^^ remove this part
   ```

   should be

   ```
   "//button[@class='c-button-template u-cursor-pointer c-button__container c-button--secondary u-color-brand u-typography-h7 u-m-t-xl)]"
   ```

   Using XPaths to match classes like this is not a good idea because it's doing a full string match. The smallest change in the classes will cause your locator to fail. Instead use a CSS selector and only add the classes that are required to find the desired element. I can't test which ones aren't needed without access to the page but the below shows the fully converted locator. `.` indicates a class in CSS syntax.

   ```
   button.c-button-template.u-cursor-pointer.c-button__container.c-button--secondary.u-color-brand.u-typography-h7.u-m-t-xl
   ```

I would suggest you go back to using `data-testid`. I think that's your best bet for a unique match on the page. A CSS selector version of that would be

```
button[data-testid="closed-odp-show-all-info"]
```

and make sure you add a wait for clickable, etc.

If that still doesn't work, you could try locating the element by contained text but I'm not sure that will be unique on the page either if the `data-testid` isn't.

```
//span[text()="Show all info"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer! I will try to get to a solution with your comments in the following days and will report back.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one <kbd>Show all info</kbd> button on the page, then may be you can try the below:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Show all info']")))
element.click()
```

Regarding the below error which you are getting:

```
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the XPath expression
```

See the correct syntax below, you will notice I have enclosed the class names with the double quote(")

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class,"c-button-template u-cursor-pointer c-button__container c-button--secondary u-color-brand u-typography-h7 u-m-t-xl")]').click()
```